# pyspark operations not scaling up

Tags: python, pyspark, out-of-memory

I have a code in a notebook that works fine but failed however on bigger data with endless computation and a *java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space*.

The process is as follows:

#### mocking pyspark data

I start with a dataframe with 3 columns namely (User, Time, and Item) as mocked in the code below:

```py
    from pyspark.sql.types import *
    from pyspark.context import SparkContext
    from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
    import pandas as pd
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
    spark = SparkSession(sc)

    df_schema = StructType([ StructField("User", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("Time", IntegerType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("Item", StringType(), True)])
    pddf = pd.DataFrame([["u1",1,"A"],
                    ["u1",1,"A"],
                    ["u1",2,"A"],
                    ["u1",3,"B"],
                    ["u1",3,"C"],
                    ["u1",4,"B"],
                    ["u2",1,"D"],
                    ["u2",2,"D"],
                    ["u2",2,"A"],
                    ["u2",2,"F"],
                    ["u2",3,"D"],
                    ["u2",3,"A"],],columns=["User", "Time", "Item"])

    df = spark.createDataFrame(pddf,schema=df_schema)
    df.show()
```

which gives

```
+----+----+----+
|User|Time|Item|
+----+----+----+
|  u1|   1|   A|
|  u1|   1|   A|
|  u1|   2|   A|
|  u1|   3|   B|
|  u1|   3|   C|
|  u1|   4|   B|
|  u2|   1|   D|
|  u2|   2|   D|
|  u2|   2|   A|
|  u2|   2|   F|
|  u2|   3|   D|
|  u2|   3|   A|
+----+----+----+
```

#### intermediate step

Then I compute the topn most common items for each user and create a dataframe with new column *uc* (uc for uncommon) which is set to 0 if item is *in topn list* or 1 otherwise.

```py
    import pyspark.sql.functions as F
    from pyspark.sql import Window
    ArrayOfTupleType = ArrayType(StructType([
        StructField("itemId", StringType(), False),
        StructField("count", IntegerType(), False)
    ]))

    @F.udf(returnType=ArrayOfTupleType)
    def most_common(x, topn=2):
        from collections import Counter
        c = Counter(x)
        mc = c.most_common(topn)
        return mc
    topn=2
    w0 = Window.partitionBy("User")
    dfd = (df.withColumn("Item_freq", most_common(F.collect_list("Item").over(w0), F.lit(topn)))
             .select("User", "Time" , "Item" , "Item_freq")
             .withColumn("mcs", F.col("Item_freq.itemId"))
             .withColumn("uc", F.when(F.expr("array_contains(mcs, Item)"), 0).otherwise(1)).cache())

    dfd.select("User", "Time", "Item" , "mcs" , "uc").show()
```

which gives the interemediate dataframe below

```
+----+----+----+------+---+
|User|Time|Item|mcs   |uc |
+----+----+----+------+---+
|u1  |1   |A   |[A, B]|0  |
|u1  |1   |A   |[A, B]|0  |
|u1  |2   |A   |[A, B]|0  |
|u1  |3   |B   |[A, B]|0  |
|u1  |3   |C   |[A, B]|1  |
|u1  |4   |B   |[A, B]|0  |
|u2  |1   |D   |[D, A]|0  |
|u2  |2   |D   |[D, A]|0  |
|u2  |2   |A   |[D, A]|0  |
|u2  |2   |F   |[D, A]|1  |
|u2  |3   |D   |[D, A]|0  |
|u2  |3   |A   |[D, A]|0  |
+----+----+----+------+---+
```

#### aggregating step

Then I finally group by user and time which is the operation that **failed on real data**:

```py
    uncommon = dfd.groupBy("User", "Time").agg(F.sum(F.col("uc")).alias("UncommonItem"))
    uncommon.orderBy("User", "Time", ascending=True).show()
```

which gives the expected results on the dummy data

```
+----+----+------------+
|User|Time|UncommonItem|
+----+----+------------+
|u1  |1   |0           |
|u1  |2   |0           |
|u1  |3   |1           |
|u1  |4   |0           |
|u2  |1   |0           |
|u2  |2   |1           |
|u2  |3   |0           |
+----+----+------------+
```

but it failed with a *java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space* on real data.

Increasing the spark.driver.memory from 6G to 60G make only the crash comming after a much longer time untill it fills the 60G. My real data has 1907505 input samples

I am not very experienced with pyspark, and I am not sure where the problem comes from. Many other groupby/agg operation elsewere are fast and do not fail on the same type of data. Therefore I am suspecting that the issue comes from the way i made my dataframe *dfd* in the intermediate step above.

Any idea on how to optimize the code?

Comment: At which line do you get OOM ?

Comment: when I call the show() method: `uncommon.orderBy("User", "Time", ascending=True).show()`. It would also occur if we call the show() method on the line above. I have just seen that i have also the OOM when calling the count() method on the dataframe named dfd in the intermediate step (just before aggregation)

Comment: Are you sure it is `show` and not `orderBy` which causes OOM ? Check that.

Comment: yes, I have the error when `orderBy` is omitted. I believe the problem occurs before, because I have also an OOM when calling the `count()` method on the `dfd` dataframe before the `groupBy` and `orderBy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are okay to change the approach , you can give the below a shot:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

topn=2
w = Window.partitionBy('User','Item')
df1 = df.withColumn("Counts",F.count('Item').over(w))

w1 = Window.partitionBy(df1["User"]).orderBy(df1['Counts'].desc())

(df1.withColumn("dummy",F.when(F.dense_rank().over(w1)<=topn,0).otherwise(1))
.groupBy('User','Time').agg(F.max("dummy").alias('UncommonItem'))).show()
```

---

```
+----+----+------------+
|User|Time|UncommonItem|
+----+----+------------+
|  u1|   1|           0|
|  u1|   2|           0|
|  u1|   3|           1|
|  u1|   4|           0|
|  u2|   1|           0|
|  u2|   2|           1|
|  u2|   3|           0|
+----+----+------------+
```

Steps followed in the answer:

1. get Count over a window of User and Item
2. get dense_rank over User and the Count returned in step1
3. Wherever rank is within 2 (topn) return 1 else 0 and named it dummy
4. group on User and time and get max of the dummy

Comment: awesome, fast and no OOM anymore, thanks. Any idea what was the bottleneck in my approach?

Comment: @Urian I feel more to do with the approach , things like `collect_list` is quite inefficient and udfs take longer than builtin methods